# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES] React native

Tags: android, react-native, installation, apk

I want to generate an apk that run it without server on react-native :

I had created a key to sign the apk.Using below to create key:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-app-key.keystore -alias my-app-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Using a password

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Generate the build using gradle

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

but when i want to install the apk with this line :

```
adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
```

I have this error :

```
5663 KB/s (8971275 bytes in 1.546s) pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release-unsigned.apk Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Comment: I was getting this error as well. After Googling a lot I realized that it was the issue of my phone(Redmi Note 8 pro)'s battery saver. I turned it off and ran the command `adb -s deviceId install -r -d /path/to/app-debug.apk` and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not signing the APK. assembleRelease by default does not do it for you.

Did you follow this part of the guide?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#adding-signing-config-to-your-app-s-gradle-config

Comment: I have this error !Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file /home/sofiane/projet/Narimene_Korso/android/app/my-release-key.keystore  not found for signing config 'release'.